# Stop Sketch adding extra pixels around a slice?

Tags: sketch-app

This is my first project working with a sketch file (given to me by a designer for me to cut up into HTML/CSS).

So far I've loved the way sketch makes exporting easy, but I'm running into some trouble here. I have a slice drawn around a couple of vector layers that form a mask over an image. I have the slice perfectly clipped to the edges of the layers, but in the preview panel (and also when I export) sketch is adding pixels around the edges.

[image: Screenshot - note extra pixels around slice preview.]

The "Trim transparent pixels" checkbox does nothing. What should I check next? Or am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your slice is tight around the shapes you want to export? Have you zoomed in to check?

Comment: @Luciano yes I zoomed in, it's definitely in the exact right spot.

Comment: Have you tried toggling the `Trim transparent pixels` option?

Comment: It's related to x and y position: be sure your object isn´t place on sub-pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **callout-bg-mask** seem to have a **box shadow**.
The slice may be a child of this layer, it still inheritates the shadow and this may cause the slice bug ; try to disable it before exporting the slice.

I tried this and have the same problem :

**Parent has a shadow :**

[image]

**Parent has no shadow :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try and export first and see if it adds the pixel around it, I think it's just for show. Temporary fix is to open in Photoshop, cmd select the layer then crop the pixels.

Comment: It does add the pixels when I export. I have for now addressed the issue by opening the exported png in photoshop and cropping it. It's still happening with other slices though so it would be good to find a fix.

Comment: What happens if you change the dimension of the slice?

Comment: Also, is your sketch the latest version? I can't find anything in my copy that affects the slice tool.

Comment: I'm on the latest version (still the trial if that's relevant). It's possible that it's got something to do with shadows.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around to this: add an artboard the size of the slice, then paste your asset into the artboard. When you export, it should be the correct size.